# The graph of Alternating current

Tags: electric-current

I am beginner Physics student and currently studying Alternating current. One thing that confuses me about this topic is the graph Voltage/Time. Now I know it is a sinusoid, but it is the representation of actually what happens? Let me explain better, shouldn't the graph be represented by just some dots (peak values) like in the image below? 
[image: Just to explain my idea]
I mean if the change of the voltage happens every second and it is immediate why do we have a sinusoid?

Comment: Why would you think it is immediate?

Comment: If your first "x" marks the voltage of your system at 1 second, and the second "x" marks the voltage at 2 seconds, what is the voltage at 1.5 seconds?

Comment: Shouldn't the voltage at 1.5 sec equal to the voltage at 1.0 sec and then immediately drop/go up?

Comment: That would be a [square wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave). But the most common form of alternating current (the one used in power grids) is indeed sinusoidal.

Comment: Ok, but then this implies that the change in voltage is not immediate? Why is that? A technical limitation?

Comment: Probably a combination of the fact that sinusoidal AC was easier to generate when AC was invented and widely adapted and that square waves has a bunch of drawbacks. What made you think it would be immediate?

Comment: Well I thought was just "obvious", I guess I absorbed that when watching an oscilloscope connected to a DC battery, where inverting positive/negative the oscilloscope shows a negative or positive straight line. I thought that was the basic implementation of how it works in reality.

Comment: Might be revelant what is your definition of AC/DC: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/112223/24361

Comment: Thanks for that link, it helped me understand this better.

Answer (score 2):

Alternating current does not necessarily have to be a sine wave, it could be a square, triangular or of arbitrary form. The definition of alternating current is just that current periodically reverses direction.

To your graph, I assume those are measurement points taken in time, with lets say a multimeter. What happens between them is unknown, as you do not have enough points, but if you simply connect the dots you will see that it is triangular, which is a common wave form for certain applications. But it might also be a sine wave like you indicated, just sampling the peak values. You simply dont know, thats why we like using analytical functions or sampling enough points to see whats going on. Sine waves used in power grids come from generators, which simply generate a sinusoidal induced voltage when rotating.